# How Can I Limit the Amount of RAM a Mac OS Application Can Use?

Tags: mac, memory, dropbox

I installed dropbox and it has terrible memory management. It often uses 3GB out of my 4GB of RAM.

Is there any way to limit the app memory usage?

I would like to never allow more than 250 MB of RAM.

Comment: How are you determining that it's using 3GB of RAM?

Comment: Which version of Dropbox are you using?

Comment: memory usage *used* to be easy to manage on a Mac: Cmd-I would give you the Info pane, and you could adjust its minimum and maximum allocations

Comment: The iStat Menus application is pretty great for watching memory, disk, CPU, etc. usage. You can also use the `top` command-line utility to look at active processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`ulimit`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ulimit.1.html) shell builtin to limit the resources, though you then have to launch Dropbox from the shell that you ran `ulimit` in, instead of from the Finder or something.

```
$ help ulimit
ulimit: ulimit [-SHacdefilmnpqrstuvx] [limit]
    Modify shell resource limits.

    Provides control over the resources available to the shell and processes
    it creates, on systems that allow such control.

    Options:
      -S        use the `soft' resource limit
      -H        use the `hard' resource limit
      -a        all current limits are reported
      -b        the socket buffer size
      -c        the maximum size of core files created
      -d        the maximum size of a process's data segment
      -e        the maximum scheduling priority (`nice')
      -f        the maximum size of files written by the shell and its children
      -i        the maximum number of pending signals
      -l        the maximum size a process may lock into memory
      -m        the maximum resident set size
      -n        the maximum number of open file descriptors
      -p        the pipe buffer size
      -q        the maximum number of bytes in POSIX message queues
      -r        the maximum real-time scheduling priority
      -s        the maximum stack size
      -t        the maximum amount of cpu time in seconds
      -u        the maximum number of user processes
      -v        the size of virtual memory
      -x        the maximum number of file locks

    If LIMIT is given, it is the new value of the specified resource; the
    special LIMIT values `soft', `hard', and `unlimited' stand for the
    current soft limit, the current hard limit, and no limit, respectively.
    Otherwise, the current value of the specified resource is printed.  If
    no option is given, then -f is assumed.

    Values are in 1024-byte increments, except for -t, which is in seconds,
    -p, which is in increments of 512 bytes, and -u, which is an unscaled
    number of processes.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or an error occurs.
```

You probably want `ulimit -m` or `ulimit -v`.

Comment: This doesn't work. I did `ulimit -m 200000` and `ulimit -v 200000` then ran an application via `/Applications/ABC.app/Contents/MacOS/ABC`. I then watched the memory climb well over 500 MB before I killed the process.

Answer (score -1):

You should replace Dropbox by an experimental build.
http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20062